# Need suggestions on how to implement genetic algorithms type application

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm new to java and can't seem to wrap my head around a problem.  I'm trying to take two arrays of stock information, and compare them against each other(only keeping the ones that appear in both arrays).  I read a bit about generic algorithms and if a match, I wanted to be able to create classes to assign fitness scores to each array set. My code doesn't really work(I can get it to analyze each individual components of the array but not the range I want it to).  To clear things up, here's a sample of my data:

```
ID   date   Ticker  Shares
    1   2011-06-19  goog    0
    1   2011-06-19  ibm 0
    1   2011-06-19  gs  0
    1   2011-06-19  msft    0
    1   2011-06-19  c   5
    2   2011-06-19  goog    0
    2   2011-06-19  ibm 0
    2   2011-06-19  gs  0
    2   2011-06-19  msft    1
    2   2011-06-19  c   4
    3   2011-06-19  goog    0
    3   2011-06-19  ibm 0
    3   2011-06-19  gs  0
    3   2011-06-19  msft    2
    3   2011-06-19  c   3
    4   2011-06-19  goog    0
    4   2011-06-19  ibm 0
    4   2011-06-19  gs  0
    4   2011-06-19  msft    3
    4   2011-06-19  c   2
    5   2011-06-19  goog    0
    5   2011-06-19  ibm 0
    5   2011-06-19  gs  0
    5   2011-06-19  msft    4
    5   2011-06-19  c   1
```

As so on, I have a array of this and another one for the previous date. I want to be able to compare(grouped by the id's) the two against each other, and find entire matches. But later on, I want to be able to take the successful matches and perform analytic on them via other classes.  I think the first step is identifying a match.  Here's my code(it only identifies a match of ticker/shares, and I'm not sure how to get it to match an entire ID set):

```
public void compare(int firstindex, int lastIndex, Object date1, ArrayList data1id, ArrayList data1ticker, ArrayList data1shares, ArrayList data1price, Object date2,  ArrayList data2id, ArrayList data2ticker, ArrayList data2shares, ArrayList data2price) throws Exception {
    ArrayList ticker = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList shares = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList price = new ArrayList(); 

    while (firstindex < lastIndex) {
        //System.out.print("date is " + date1);
        ticker.add(data1ticker.get(firstindex));
        shares.add(data1shares.get(firstindex));
        price.add(data1price.get(firstindex));
        firstindex++;
    }
    comparewithsecondarray(ticker, shares, price, date2, data2id, data2ticker, data2shares, data2price);
    //System.out.println("***********");
}

public void comparewithsecondarray(ArrayList tickerarray, ArrayList sharesarray, ArrayList pricearray, Object date2,  ArrayList data2id, ArrayList data2ticker, ArrayList data2shares, ArrayList data2price) throws Exception {
//get the total number of values in the array
int totalArrayList = tickerarray.size();
int counter= 0;

        System.out.println("Array has been checked against second array and we're on " + counter);
        System.out.println(tickerarray);
        System.out.println(sharesarray);
        System.out.println("+++++++");

    while (counter < totalArrayList) {

        Object ticker = tickerarray.get(counter);
        Object shares = sharesarray.get(counter);
        Object price = pricearray.get(counter);


        loadSecondArray(ticker, shares, price, date2, data2id, data2ticker, data2shares, data2price);
        counter++;
    }

}

public void loadSecondArray(Object ticker, Object shares, Object price, Object date2,  ArrayList data2id, ArrayList data2ticker, ArrayList data2shares, ArrayList data2price) throws Exception {
    //System.out.println("ticker " + ticker);
    //System.out.println("shares " + shares);
    //System.out.println("price " + price);

    //find the last number of the arrray
    if (!data2id.isEmpty()) {
        int counter2 = Integer.parseInt(data2id.get(data2id.size()-1).toString());
        //System.out.println("last element in array2 is " + counter2);
    }        

    //location is the id number we're looking for.
    int location = 1;
    while (location > counter2) {
        boolean blnFound = data2id.contains(location);
        //System.out.println("Does arrayList contain " + location + "? " + blnFound);
        if (blnFound) {

            if(firstindex == -1) {
                //System.out.println("ArrayList does not contain " + location);
            } else {
                //System.out.println("ArrayList contains " + location  + " at index :" + firstindex);
                int firstindex = data2id.indexOf(location);
                int lastIndex = data2id.lastIndexOf(location);
                //send ranges to study

                while (firstindex < lastIndex) {
                    //System.out.print("date is " + date1);
                    Object ticker2 = data2ticker.get(firstindex);
                    Object shares2= data2shares.get(firstindex);
                    Object price2 = data2price.get(firstindex);
                    if (ticker.equals(ticker2) &&  shares.equals(shares2)) {
                        System.out.println("We have a match!");
                        System.out.println(ticker);
                        System.out.println(ticker2);
                        System.out.println(shares);
                        System.out.println(shares2);
                        System.out.println("*****");
                    }
                    //add to the counter
                    firstindex++;
                }

                location++;
            }



        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Sorry in advance for the quality of the code, I'm pretty new and still learning. I think the first step is to identify the matches, then have a way to pass those matches(as arraylists, I guess) to other classes to analyze.

Any suggestions on how to achieve my goals of this project would be great(I am reading a book on genetic algo's but its a bit hard to grasp so I'm starting to review all the code I can find on the interne to understand how its being done).

Thanks in advance

Comment: genetic algorithms, which I have a very low regard for, don't sound remotely applicable to this problem.

Comment: It seems like you need to totally rethink your design.  I will try to post an answer based on what it appears you are looking for.

Comment: There are a lot of problems here-- First, I would use actual types (String, Integer) instead of making everything an Object.  Second, I would think about creating an object to associate all the attributes that make up a single stock rice data item (id, ticker, quantity, price) and deal with that as a unit.  You need to get the basics down before you try tackling something leading edge like genetic algorithms.

Comment: Regarding @antlersoft's comment on types, OP may like to read up on [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html) in Java, introduced in 2004.

Comment: Thanks Atrey I'll read up on it.  
@antlersoft, I was using objects instead of converting everything everytime, and was going to convert it to the actual types when I needed to analyze the results.  
@MirroredFate, Yes I realize now that there are big issues with my design itself. I'm a bit new to coding so I'm not 100% sure how to design it(I'm going to find books on it as I have only worked/studied small code snippets).
@David..I am not 100% it applies either, but the idea of the fitness score really applies to my problem, and changing based on the relative result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need something like this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

//class representing all your data
public class StockData implements Comparable<StockData>{
    private int id;
    private Calendar date;
    private List<ShareBean> shares;

//this will return whichever StockData that has more total shares as being greater
@Override
public int compareTo(StockData arg0) {
    int totalshares = 0;
    int totalshares2 = 0;
    for(ShareBean share: shares)
        totalshares+=share.getShares();
    for(ShareBean share: arg0.getShares())
        totalshares2+=share.getShares();
    return totalshares-totalshares2;
}
    //this method is used to see if another StockData object has the same id
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        try {
        StockData arg1 = (StockData) arg0;
        if (id == arg1.id)
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public Calendar getDate() {
    return date;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
    }


    public void setShares(List<ShareBean> shares) {
    this.shares = shares;
    }

    public List<ShareBean> getShares() {
    return shares;
    }

public String toString(){
    String toReturn = "";
    toReturn+="ID: "+id+"\n";
    toReturn+="Date: "+date.getTime()+"\n";
    for(ShareBean share: shares)
        toReturn+="Shares: "+share.toString()+"\n";
    return toReturn;
}
}
```

Using this, you just make a StockData object for every datapiece you have, and add it to an array of such objects.  Then, should you wish to find out if they are the same, you just use the `.equals(Object arg0)` method of StockData, and compare it to another StockData object.

For instance:

```
//this method compares to Lists of StockData, and returns a list containing all
//the StockData objects that had matches
public List<StockData> comparewithsecondarray(List<StockData> StockData1, List<StockData> StockData2) {
List<StockData> list = new ArrayList<StockData>();

for(StockData sd1: StockData1){
   for(StockData sd2: StockData2){
      if(sd1.equals(sd2)){
         //found a match!  add it to the list
         list.add(sd1);
         //break so we don't add the same object multiple times
         break;
      }
   }
}
return list;
}
```

It really looks like you have made this incredibly more complex than it needs to be.  If you were to repost what SPECIFICALLY you want to do, it would make answering your question easier.

EDIT: I've modified my StockData class, and added this other class to keep track of shares:

public class ShareBean {
    private String ticker;
    private int shares;

```
public ShareBean(String ticker, int shares){
    this.ticker = ticker;
    this.shares = shares;
}

public void setTicker(String ticker) {
    this.ticker = ticker;
}
public String getTicker() {
    return ticker;
}
public void setShares(int shares) {
    this.shares = shares;
}
public int getShares() {
    return shares;
}


public String toString(){
    String toReturn = "";
    toReturn+="Ticker: "+ticker+", Shares: "+shares;
    return toReturn;
}
}
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

Put this main method somewhere... it doesn't really matter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<StockData> listSD1 = new ArrayList<StockData>();
    List<StockData> listSD2 = new ArrayList<StockData>();

    StockData sd1 = new StockData();
    StockData sd2 = new StockData();
    List<ShareBean> listShares1 = new ArrayList<ShareBean>();
    List<ShareBean> listShares2 = new ArrayList<ShareBean>();

    //create the shares for sd1
    listShares1.add(new ShareBean("goog", 3));
    listShares1.add(new ShareBean("ibm", 5));
    listShares1.add(new ShareBean("gs", 0));
    listShares1.add(new ShareBean("msft", 0));
    listShares1.add(new ShareBean("c", 1));

    //create the shares for sd2
    listShares2.add(new ShareBean("goog", 0));
    listShares2.add(new ShareBean("ibm", 1));
    listShares2.add(new ShareBean("gs", 3));
    listShares2.add(new ShareBean("msft", 0));
    listShares2.add(new ShareBean("c", 5));

    //set their ids
    sd1.setId(1);
    sd2.setId(2);

    //set the dates (using calendars)
    sd1.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    sd2.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    //and finally set the shares
    sd1.setShares(listShares1);
    sd2.setShares(listShares2);

    //now add each object to each list.  the lists will be exacly the same
    listSD1.add(sd1);
    listSD1.add(sd2);
    listSD2.add(sd1);
    listSD2.add(sd2);

    //now the lists are ready, and we can compare them
    //I put the comparewithsecondarray method in the StockData class, but it could go anywhere
    //I also overrode the "toString" method to make the output more readable (in both StockData and ShareBean)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sd1.comparewithsecondarray(listSD1, listSD2).toArray()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much MirroredFate..Right now I'm not 100% sure of the end result.  The only task I have is to remove duplicates and to create it in a way that others can assign "scores" based on rules they set. The only example I was given was, in this case, they might rank groups with 2 or less stocks higher then groups with more than that number of stocks..or stocks with an average price of less then a $1 get a higher value, etc..

Comment: Ahh, and that is where the "compareTo" method comes in. Read about how it works.  I believe you will find it useful. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: Thank you so much Mirroredfate, there's alot of commands in there that I have not used before, so I'll play around with the code and understand it.  I was wondering, would the compareTo method work if the stocks are not in the same order? For example, 1 share of ibm and 2 shares of GS should match 2 shares of GS and 1 share of IBM. I always thought I had to break the array down in order to compare like that.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that question.  The compareTo method is meant to be primarily used for ordering a collection.  When you call "Collections.sort(List<T extends comparable> a)", it will sort the List based upon the compareTo method.  The compareTo method sure return a negative integer if it is less than the object being compared, zero if they are the same, and a positive integer if it is greater.  So... I think my StockData class is wrong, I will edit it.

Comment: Thanks MirroredFate, I kind of understand it now, but I'm really new to java and I'm sorry for this dumb question but I'm not exactly sure how to call this.  I put it into my code but not sure what list variables to send to it. In my code I used multiple arrays and each basically was linked to the others(the first in arrayshares and arrayprice and arrayticker all refered to the same stock), this seems to want only 2 lists(List<StockData> StockData1, List<StockData> StockData2), i'm not sure what format it wants.

Comment: I understand how ShareBean works and I think I know how to add elements to it but I'm still not sure what to send to comparewithsecondarray method.

Comment: Ok, so....  I gave you a class called "StockData".  That class contains all of the StockData information for a single ID (in theory).  Now, if you wish to compare two Lists of StockData, you just put them into the comparewithsecondarray method.  The comparewithsecondarray method that I gave you will (right now) just give you back a list that has all of the IDs that existed in both of the arrays passed into the method.  If you modify the ".equals(Object arg0)" method of StockData, it will return a list based upon something else.  I will give you a code example.

Comment: Thanks mirroredFate, I understood that part of the code but what confused me is: public List<StockData> comparewithsecondarray(List<StockData> StockData1, List<StockData> StockData2)    I still can't seem to figure out what am sending in those arrays? I thought you could only have one item per row of array, I thought it was taking everything and then spliting them in the sharebean class, i'm a bit confused about that part.  Sorry I'm super new to java.

Comment: Lol I can tell.  I'm really giving you shortcuts here.  You're going to want to read this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html.   Essentially the StockData class contains all the information you need.  It is only one (1) item, but it contains more items within it (like the sharebeans).  It's like a car.  A car has many parts (wheels, seats, gears, etc.), but it is really only ONE item (a car!). StockData has many parts, but is only one item.  So, you make a bunch of StockDatas, and then put them in the arrays.

Comment: lol thanks for understanding.  I am reading the book version of those tutorials but I'm just confused on what I am sending to Stockdata so in my app I send data to my classes using something like public void compareArrays(Object date1, ArrayList data1id, ArrayList data1ticker, ArrayList data1shares, ArrayList data1price, Object date2,  ArrayList data2id, ArrayList data2ticker, ArrayList data2shares, ArrayList data2price) throws Exception {...but I'm not sure what to send to this script.

Comment: but for Like in the List<StockData> comparewithsecondarray(List<StockData> StockData1, List<StockData> StockData2), I'm not sure what I'm including in StockData1, I tried sending the ticker as stockdata1 arraylist and the shares as the second array but I got errors.

Comment: oh sorry I just saw your edit..let me study it and get back to you.  lol i'm sure I'll have some dumber questions(if its possible to get even dumber).  Thanks as always your very helpful and extremely patience.  Thanks alot!

Comment: ok maybe I need to read up on java more this weekend.  I'm approaching a problem that I had before but I could fix in my own way.  When I try your main class, it gives me an error with "StockData sd1 = new StockData();" because I cannot reference non-static methods in a static context, but when I remove the static part of the when you declare the class, it gives me an error with sending out to comparewithsecondarray, in the past I would just create another class in another file and reference it from there.lol I know what I'm studying this weekend.  Sorry my background is in fiance not coding

Comment: Copy the "public static void main(String[] args)" method EXACTLY and put it in the StockData class, then try running it from there (make sure the comparewithsecondarray method is inside StockData class also). I think you may be confused about the difference between a method and a class.  Classes contain methods (or functions).  You can make a method static, but not a class.  The best thing you can do right now is read up on Java and some basic things, like global/local variables, methods, keywords, and arrays.  Mostly try to understand methods.

Comment: ahh I understand now.  I was running it outside the class.  I'll try it out.  I basically studied perl for one semester as a student(many many years ago) and have been basically creating my applications like one large script(although a few of my apps work, they are just one main class).  Thank you so much for your help, Because of you I will spend this weekend reading the java tutorials  and just bought Bruce Eckel's thinking in java.  I can't thank you enough for your direction and patience.

Comment: Sure, happy to help.  Good luck to you!